# XAML text binding

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I would bind a string property to text property like this: `Text="{Binding propertyName}`.

I also want to append a hardcoded string to this like `Text="{Binding propertyName} appendedName`. How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text="{Binding propertyName,StringFormat='Your property is: {}{0}'}"

Answer (score 2):

You could use Run Text:

```
<TextBlock>
<Run Text="{Binding YourBinding}"/>
<Run Text="Suffix"/>
</TextBlock>
```

If you want to use it like this several times I would recommend a TemplatedControl where you have a Suffix DependencyProperty and a Text DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 1):

You should create new property that returns text + appendedName. 
Another way is to use several text blocks.

Comment: there's no straightforward way? like "{Binding propertyName} suffix" like Flex